# How to update Plot.js graph from getting data from WebSockets(Socket.io) in real-time to create time series line chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, plotly, real-time

I am using a Javascript framework [Ploty.ly]((https://plot.ly/) to plot data which is JSON Object coming from socket.io Server in real-time. With the code I provided, it is able to plot my graph but the graph is not drawn in real-time (not immediately).

Can you tell me what I did wrong or suggest me other frameworks which I can use to plot my data with sample codes?

```
   /*
        Object 0
   */
   [
        {timestamp: 157466208909, ecg: -325},
        {timestamp: 157466208998, ecg: -327},
        {timestamp: 157466208106, ecg: -327},
        {timestamp: 157466208114, ecg: -339},
   ]
    /*
        Another Update Object 1
   */
   [
        {timestamp: 157466208909, ecg: -325},
        {timestamp: 157466208998, ecg: -327},
        {timestamp: 157466208106, ecg: -327},
        {timestamp: 157466208114, ecg: -339},
   ]
    *
    *
    *
    *
```

Then I use the code below to initialize my graph and update it whenever there's an update from a server (socket.io)

```
    /*
            Socket constructor
        */
        var socket = io();
        /*
            Add initial values to graph
        */
        var time = new Date();
        var dataGraph = 
        [{
              x: [time],
              y: [0],
              mode: 'lines',
              line: {color: '#80CAF6'}
        }]

    */
        Plotly.newPlot('graph', dataGraph,layout, {showSendToCloud: true});
        /*
            Subscribe and listen to ecgData channel and listens for oncoming messages
        */
        socket.on('ecgData', function(data)
        {
            /*
                data is the json object containing ecg and timestamp
            */
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                /*
                    Creat domain from new timestamp
                */
                var time = new Date(data[i].timestamp);
                /*
                    Extend the new points to the graph data
                */      
                var update = 
                {
                      x:  [[time]],
                      y: [[data[i].ecg]]
                }   
                /*
                    Redraw the graph
                */
                Plotly.extendTraces('graph', update, [0])
            }
        });
```

I just Updated this question to Add the Screenshot at each time I get a message from server. This shows at single second I can get more than one JSON object to plot[Screenshot of console showing time at which I get update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9V2Ux.png)

Comment: What do you mean by 'real time' ? There will always be a delay in the message response from the socket. There isn't really anything you can do about network timing when it comes to frameworks.

Comment: 'Not drawn in real-time', how long is the delay and can you console log the response if the socket lags or the drawing of the chart?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. At **one second** I can get an update of 3 or more JSON objects to plot, i.e getting data updates more than once at a single second.

Comment: @Domino987 I have just edited the question to add the console logs at of time at which I get the update.

Comment: @DanielDuong the message is sent to my client app from the server in no delay, the delay is in plotting the data. As more data is coming from the server at the speed of time. The server would send the JSON object message to the plot more than once in a single second.

Comment: If it's not too much trouble could you throw the code into codesandbox.io ?
I would happily go into it and make adjustments and see where the problems lay.

There are a bunch of ways to make react more performant.
I suggest you adopt react hooks pattern and put your socket connection in a useEffects hook.

Comment: Thank you @DanielDuong, I am putting it now to codesandbox.io.

Comment: Hi, Again @DanielDuong I have uploaded it as a GIT hub repository as it was taking a long time for me to upload the data source files at https://codesandbox.io/. Please access it here: [link](https://github.com/fezekilePlaatyi/plotly_real_time_updates)

Comment: @nasiphivinqishe You don't have any React code in the repo. Just a read me.
I need to see your code to show you why there is a delay in real time rendering.

Comment: It is Jquery inside index.html file on src folder.